# Не приходят клавиши буквы и цифры в событии OnKeyDown

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-berlin

```
procedure TForm2.Edit2KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; var KeyChar: Char;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  form2.Caption := inttostr(key);
end;
```

В общем обработчик событий коды всех клавиш с цифрами и буквами считает за '0'.
То бишь у остальных клавиш все норм (например Enter определяет как положено '13').

В общем создавал я `Multi-Device` форму. В ней этот косяк обнаружил.
Кстати `KeyPreview` в свойствах формы отсутствует.

Попробовал VCL все работает как и должно.

В `Multi-Device` форме в свойствах компонентов ничего не нашел, короче буквы и цифры так и не работают.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ IZVERG (перенесен из комментария):

> Если нажатая клавиша это печатный символ или цифра, то параметр `Key` будет равен 0, а этот символ будет записан в параметр `KeyChar`. На событие `OnKeyDown` пишем:
>
> ```
> // клавиша '0'...
> if keyChar in ['0'] then
> begin
>   // здесь код
> end;
> ```